# Object oriented programming and asymptotic run-time

Tags: algorithm, oop, asymptotic-complexity

Are some ways of structuring a class hierarchy more efficient than others? Is there a way to measure this? How do design patterns factor in to computational complexity? Am I just thinking about this wrong? Just curious.

Comment: These questions are *very* broad. Not to mention any answers would be irrelevant anyway (design trumpfs performance almost universally, and if you have to ask if your case is an exception, it isn't).

Answer (score 2):

Object-oriented programming has nothing to do with algorithms (and thus asymptotic runtime), it's just a popular way of structuring programs in an attempt to make them more flexible and resistant to change.

Same for design patterns.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't introduce silly bugs in your OO code, asymptotic complexity of any algorithm won't change. Constant multiplier in formula for memory consumption/running time of your particular algorithm can change, but not it's asymptotic behavior. But this change , usually, is practically unimportant.